# Jasmine 2 - Get total success and fail specs and set it into a var

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

Is there a way to get the count of the success and failed specs?

for example:

```
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log(jasmine.SUCCESS, jasmine.FAILURES);
  }
```

Something like that.

I use the following libraries

- protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter
- jasmine-reporters

Thank you!

Comment: jasmine does not exposed any execution details. You should probably parse your reporter output to achieve that.

Comment: Indeed I had to use jasmine-json-test-reporter. And then parse to get the results.